# Which user does Eclipse login need for push to Github?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, ssh

I want to use GitHub and Eclipse for my Python project, but I have difficulties with it. Detailed steps are below, this is the short version of the question: I managed to create a repository in GitHub, import it in Eclipse, connect a project to it and make local commits. Now, when I want to push my branch, I have to fill out a username and password. I have tried my GitHub username+password, my SSH key emailaddress + password and my computer username+password, but none of these seem to work. Which username is required in this screen? Is there something else that I am forgetting?

Steps taken so far:

1) Create a GitHub repository
[image: GitHub repository]

2) Generate a SSH key for my computer, following https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/
[image: SSH key]

3) Import the repository in Eclipse
File -> Import -> Projects from Git -> Clone URI
In Authentication, I fill in my GitHub username and password
[image: Import settings]

4) In PyDev Package Explorer, Team -> Share project
I use the repository just added
[image: Share project]

5) Without doing anything to the project, I choose Team -> Commit
I commit and push both files
[image: Push settings]

6) Now, it asks me for a login user and password
[image: Login required]

I have tried my GitHub username+password, my SSH key emailaddress + password and my computer username+password, but none of these seem to work.
[image: Login failed]

**Which username is required here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an https url, you need your GitHub account username + password.
That is, unless you have [2FA activated (2 Factor Authentication)](https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/). In which case, you would need a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/)

If you are using an ssh url, *then* the ssh passphrase would be required (if you protected your private ssh key with a passphrase)

---

The [OP physicalattraction](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469465/physicalattraction) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363802/which-user-does-eclipse-login-need-for-push-to-github/28363906?noredirect=1#comment45069664_28363906):

> It turned out that I used the wrong password. Why was this not discovered in step 3, where I was importing the repository into Eclipse?

That would be because a GitHub repo is by default public (like https://github.com/physicalattraction/aurora_public is), which means no password (no authentication) is required for cloning a repo. Only for pushing to a repo.

Comment: Thanks! It turned out that I used the wrong password. Why was this not discovered in step 3, where I was importing the repository into Eclipse?

Comment: @physicalattraction I have edited the answer to answer your comment.